# Will I be allowed to bring 3 iPhones to Argentina (Buenos Aires) from the US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, argentina, buenos-aires

I am traveling to Buenos Aires next month (from the US) and I wanted to bring an iphone as a gift for my sister and her husband who currently live there. I will also have my own iphone bringing it to a total of 3 iphones.

Will I run into any issues at customs? Will I be subject to any fees or taxes?

Additional info: I am a US passport holder and I will be stopping at Bogota, Colombia for a day.

Comment: Don't bring your own iphone, you shouldn't need it there, should you? Just put your SIM into one of the new ones. This way you can at least save one device (unless you can't really spend the last day of your visit without an iPhone).

Comment: @tohecz Ah, yes. But what if the iPhone happens to be a CDMA-only model? Such phones don't have SIM card trays in them.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I have no more than zero idea what you speak about. (This smartphone stuff is getting ridiculous, after all.)

Comment: @tohecz The CDMA version (Verizon or Sprint) iPhone 4 has no SIM card tray. The GSM one (AT&T) does. Newer iPhones have SIM card trays in all models, no matter what technology they use.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi If it's CDMA, it wouldn't work there anyway. There do not appear to be any CDMA networks in Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stepping out of the airport in Columbia then you might have a problem as you will be required to go through customs there.

As far as taking the phones into Argentina it depends. Usually you are only allowed ONE device per device class(i.e. cellphone, tablet, camera, laptop) per person. So legally if you bring more than that in you will either have to pay an importation tax or they can be seized.

Comment: This is correct - they'll let you bring one in, but any more and you'll be hit with tax, which can be as much as the cost of the phone. Avoiding that would require smuggling them, ie not declaring and hoping for the best, which I cannot recommend.

I've entered Brazil (which has similar rules) with 2 laptops before and didn't get checked, but you'll basically be leaving it down to luck as to whether you get them in at all.